# phonegap - windows 10 app packaging

Tags: cordova, windows-10, packaging

I wasn't sure if this is phonegap / cordova issue or Visual Studio issue.

So, here's the fairy tale.

Now, I'm building windows 10 phone using phonegap. 
App is completed and published in iOS and Android (No problem). 
For Windows 10, I built app using 'phonegap build windows' command.
Of course there was an error regarding 'You must specify cpu type' and such.
However as we all know, it doesn't mean that the build had been failed .

I used visual studio 2015 Enterprise to open the app project. 
Since I don't want windows 8.1, I 'unloaded' windows 8.1 phone and desktop. 
Then changed settings to 'release' 'arm' 'device' and started to build. 
Build succeeded. 
Deploy to the device, succeeded. 
App is running awesome in Lumia 650 device.

Now, started to package the app. 
After all steps, upload file has been created. 
Then I uploaded the file in the dashboard.

Time passed and when I checked and downloaded my app on the app store, 
It doesn't run properly. 
It shows the splash screen then...nothing. Just a white screen.

Does anyone has an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Same here with Windows 10. Will be glad if anyone has an idea what is going on.

Comment: I've contacted Microsoft and troubleshooted using skype.
Even the engineer from Microsoft couldn't solve this. Later, I sent him log files to analyze and turns out that the exception record is empty.
His suggestion was to look at the opening view. See if the edge browsers can load the html5 page.